# huggingface transformer issue

Tags: python, bert-language-model, transformer-model, huggingface

I used huggingface transformer, but I got some issues like below.
How can I handle this problem?

```
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./.checkpoints',
    num_train_epochs=config.n_epochs,
    per_device_train_batch_size=config.batch_size_per_device,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=config.batch_size_per_device,
    warmup_steps=n_warmup_steps,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    fp16=True,
    evaluation_strategy='epoch',
    save_strategy='epoch',
    logging_steps=n_total_iterations // 100,
    save_steps=n_total_iterations // config.n_epochs,
    load_best_model_at_end=True, )
```

---

```
  File "finetune_plm_hftrainer.py", line 134, in main
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
  File "<string>", line 90, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/training_args.py", line 813, in __post_init__
    raise ValueError(f"logging strategy {self.logging_strategy} requires non-zero --logging_steps")
ValueError: logging strategy IntervalStrategy.STEPS requires non-zero --logging_steps
```

Comment: Can you provide more context ? The code, the imports, the versions of hugging face and python.

Answer (score 2):

When setting `logging_steps=n_total_iterations // 100` you are risking that `logging_steps` will be zero if `n_total_iterations < 100`.

In order to make sure you don't input zero:

```
logging_steps = max(1, n_total_iterations // 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an incorrect value on the flag `--loging_steps` it should be an integer > 0, and it determines the interval for logging, a number larger than 50 should be fine. more info [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/897a8dd89f40817201bc4aebe532a096405bdeb1/src/transformers/training_args.py#L945).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the piece of code responsible of raising the error you are getting:

```
# logging_steps must be non-zero for logging_strategy that is other than 'no'
       if self.logging_strategy == IntervalStrategy.STEPS and self.logging_steps == 0:
       raise ValueError(f"logging strategy {self.logging_strategy} requires non-zero --logging_steps")
```

source: [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/training_args.py), lines from 1008 to 1010.

Most probably `n_total_iterations // 100` become zero for some values, and that's forbidden if you are using `IntervalStrategy.STEPS` as loggin strategy, so i suggest you to check the value of `n_total_iterations`.